# Segfault in C File I/O

Tags: c, file-io

I'm trying to read in a string of text from a FILE*, but every time I try I get a segmentation fault. This is the only thing I'm doing in the program, so I'm not really sure why this is happening.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
  FILE* file;
  char* string;
  file = fopen("practice.txt", "r");
  fgets(string, 100, file);
  printf("%s", string);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please check for "`file = fopen() == NULL`".  OK? ;)  After that, please make sure you've allocated space for "fgets()" to read something into.  "`char string[80]`" and "`fgets (string, sizeof(string), file)`" will work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You haven't allocated any memory for your string. You can use [malloc](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/malloc/) to allocate memory for your string, or use an array `char string[100];`

Comment: I changed it to char string[100] and now it works. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @nh0815 - Be sure to check if "fopen()" fails.  And I'd strongly urge you to use a #define and/or "sizeof()" to make sure the #/bytes you allow in fgets ("100") always matches the #/bytes in your buffer ("string[100]").  IMHO...

Answer (score 3):

Be sure to allocate memory to store what you're going to read:

```
char string[101];
```

Answer (score 1):

That is because the `string` is uninitialized. `string` is a `char *` and initially holds garbage value as an address, which is dereferenced by the `fgets` function, resulting in undefined behaviour.

Either do

```
char string[BUFFER_LEN];
```

And define `BUFFER_LEN` appropriately

or do

```
char *string;
string = malloc (sizeof (char) * buf_siz);
```

where `buf_siz` holds the length of the buffer.
When you dynamically allocate the string, remember to `free (string)` when you have finished working with the memory block allocated with `malloc`, it is a good practice, and will prevent memory leak in larger programs.

Always check if the file was opened successfully by checking the return value of `fopen` . If it returns `NULL` then the open operation failed. Else it will return the `FILE` pointer.

Answer (score 1):

`char *string` declares a pointer, but doesn't set it to point anywhere meaningful; you haven't allocated any memory to store the text read from the file.

You either need to allocate an array, like so:

```
char string[101] = {0}; 
...
fread(string,100,file);
printf("%s\n", string);
```

or allocate the memory at runtime:

```
char *string;
...
string = calloc(101, sizeof *string);
if (string)
{
  fread(string,100,file)
  printf("%s\n", string);
  free(string);
}
```

In both cases we allocate enough memory for 101 characters to account for the 0 terminator, and since `fread` won't write a 0 terminator to the end of the input, we initialize the memory to all-bits-zero in both cases (the first by using an initializer, the second with the call to `calloc`).